# How to remove certain characters from HTML code using ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, character-encoding

Just like the title says, how do I  tell the page to output the HTML code and remove certain characters, such as this character (**ü**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a method that removes diacritics:

```
public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string input)
{
    input = input.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(input[i]) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark) 
            output.Append(input[i]);
    }

    return output.ToString();
}
```

Example usage:

```
string str = RemoveDiacritics("éïå"); // str = "eia"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean specific enumerated characters, or all characters with diacritics? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic

```
 myString = Replace(myString, "ü", "")
```