# Upload file with åäö in filename

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

While uploading images with the char å, ä or ö everthing gets messed up.
Tried to to .replace("å", "a") and so on but that didn't help.

```
String fileName = Path.GetFileName(files[i].FileName).Replace(" ", "").Replace("å", "a").Replace("ö", "o").Replace("ä", "ae");
```

Anyone knows how to resolve this?

Thanks
M

Comment: What do you mean by "everything gets messed up" exactly? I can't imagine that *everything* gets messed up, so what does, and in what way?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. File names uploaded, "Nyår 2011 21455.jpg" becomes something like "_PFPHV20" when saved to the server. If I try to add extension to "_PFPHV20" ("_PFPHV20.jpg") I'm still unable to open the image.

Comment: See my answer to this question for a method that removea the diacritics from a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545790/how-to-remove-certain-characters-from-html-code-using-asp/5546061#5546061

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC doesn't Replace return the string? So just doing Replace on an existing string doesn't change it.

IOW:

```
files[i].FileName =(files[i].FileName).Replace(" ", "").Replace("å", "a").Replace("ö", "o").Replace("ä", "ae")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the filename with Server.HTMLEncode(files[i].FileName) that may fix your problem.